# Can a Linux Web Server also be a Firewall and Router?

Tags: linux, networking, router, firewall

I have a Linux web server, assigned a public "dynamic" IPv4 and Public IPv6 from my ISP.

I have a small router, but because of the CPU limitations it maxes out at 500mb/s, and doesn't have a robust firewall (basically just some DDOS protection and MAC filtering).

My box has two Ethernet interfaces and I was wondering if I could plug in a cable from my ISP modem into the second interface than have the box route and firewall the traffic. The firewall would block all incoming traffic and block known malware ports on outgoing traffic.

But, I don't want my web server and other interfaces listening on that second interface, and I don't web traffic being routed through the first interface. Basically I want the setup to look like this

```
Internet <==> | Linux        |
Internet <==> | Server/Router | <==> Switch
```

Is this possible, and if so how can I go about achieving this?

Comment: Yes, and do you have enough RAM and processing power to make it work? What's your CPU, RAM, and motherboard? Please click [edit] to add that useful information; please do not click Add Comment, but instead use [edit].

Comment: I suggest running on the same physical machine, but use some kind of virtualisation to separate the systems logically. Maybe look into Docker or esxi.

Comment: @daniel, wouldn't it be easier to use iptables and bridge/forward the traffic across interfaces?

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve isolation you will need VMware esxi or similar.

Each interface gets its own IP address.  You can easily go into the config file, and change what IP address the service listens on.

Normally all traffic would flow through the NIC connected to the ISP.  Except for traffic destine only for the IP on the internal side.  This is not necessarily bad, as your services will ignore traffic not meant for them, and you use IPTABLES in linux to block all bad traffic on each port.

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT --dports 80,443
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP

iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP  -m multiport -m state --state NEW --dports 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15
```

You can only block 15 entries per command with multiport.

The traffic is still going to have to flow like this except if you use VMWare esxi you can isolate each virtual machine way more.  Even so if a computer on NIC B want to access the internet it has to go through NIC A ( connected to ISP)

You can even create a 3rd firewall VM which the NICs are physically connected to, but then it only forwards the traffic you specify to the correct virtual machines.

You can use FORWARDING group to control what gets passed from NIC 1 to NIC 2, and vice versa.